# Cucumber + JUnit5 + gradle + kotlin

Tags: kotlin, junit, cucumber

Im trying to port my cucumber scenarios from JUnit 4 to JUnit 5 (to run in parallel)

I have entry class

```
package com.wms.test

@io.cucumber.junit.platform.engine.Cucumber
class MyTest
```

and package with step definitions: com.wms.test.glue.
Also I have feature-files in resources/features.

I've also specified junit property in gradle.build:

```
dependencies {
    testImplementation
           "io.cucumber:cucumber-java8:5.7.0",
            "io.cucumber:cucumber-junit-platform-engine:5.7.0",
            "io.cucumber:cucumber-spring:5.7.0",
            "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test"
}
test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
    systemProperties = [
            'cucumber.glue': 'com.wms.test.glue'
    ]
    testLogging {
        events "passed", "skipped", "failed"
    }
}
```

When I call ./gradlew test I got message:

```
BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 3s
6 actionable tasks: 6 executed
```

No tests were running.

If I call Idea to run tests on MyTest -

```
No tests found for given includes: [com.wms.test.MyTest](filter.includeTestsMatching)
```

Please help

Comment: You'll have to use the JUnitConsoleLauncher https://github.com/gradle/gradle/issues/4773#issuecomment-451074254

Comment: Given that the console launcher workaround is so horrible, it's probably easier to stay on JUnit 4 until it's fixed. :(

Comment: You can now use the Suite Engine from the JUnit Platform instead of the Console Launcher. Works decently. https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-jvm/tree/main/cucumber-junit-platform-engine